# Filtering in Kanban board in TFS 2015 not working for tags with spaces

Tags: tfs-2015, kanban

When I try to filter the Kanban board with tag names containing space, then it does not give proper result.

For example: When I search for **"feature 1"**, then the result looks something like this:

But, I need results only with **"feature 1"**.
Is this the expected behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's because filtering on the Kanban board consumes other fields of the backlog items (at least, title), **not only tags**. Besides, the words separated by white space in the filtering field seem to be searched separately.

As far as I can see, couple of your PBIs have " 1" in the name. That's why when you search for "feature 1" it finds those with "feature 1" tab **and** those with " 1" in the title. Rename the PBIs to something real and that won't be the case.

This definitely looks like a bug, no doubt.